# trying to get custom product attribute's link value

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have custom product attribute for every product in my store. The attribute code is `product_link`.

I have this code to get all products in the current cart session:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $ProductLink = $item->getProduct()->getProductLink();
    $ProductName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    echo "ProductLink: $ProductLink - ProductName: $ProductName<br>";
}
```

I have no problem to get the name of the product which is a default attribute.
However, I cannot get the link value in `product_link` attribute which all products have.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```
$ProductLink = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getProductLink();
```

Comment: It's unclear how this answer is supposed to help. Where is this line supposed to go? Is it in addition to your code above or replacing something? What was missing that you added here?